# Der Unterschied zwischen den Ausdrücken »unter Bewährung sein« und »auf Bewährung sein«

Tags: preposition, verb-usage, verb-choice

> 1. Ich stehe drei Jahre unter Bewährung.
> 2. Ich bin drei Jahre auf Bewährung.

Ich frage mich, ob *unter* die selbe Bedeutung wie *auf* hat oder ist diese Präposition anders als die andere? Und kann ich in diesem Zusammenhang entweder *stehen* oder *sein* benutzen?

Comment: Den zweiten Satz kannst du nur mündlich verwenden, und auch dann wirkt er zumindest auf mich sehr deppenhaft. Genau das, was ich von einem, der auf Bewährung draußen ist, zu hören erwarte. Manche Sprecher verwenden auch *haben* statt *sein*.

Comment: @Janka "deppenhaft" ist möglicherweise ein bisschen daneben. "Was macht der Hoeneß?" - "Der ist auf Bewährung draußen" kann auch in der Zeitung stehen.

Comment: Ist der erste Satz nicht eine Abkürzung von "Ich stehe drei Jahre unter Bewährungsstrafe", folgt also dem Ausdruck "unter Strafe stehen"?

Comment: @tofro: Da hast du aber einen anderen, vollständigen Satz gebildet. *Ich bin auf Bewährung **draußen**.* Draußen sein ist eine gängige Ortsangabe, Bewährung eine zusätzliche Bedingung dafür – was ja auch der Sinn einer Bewährung ist. Der ursprüngliche Satz lässt die Ortsangabe aus: *Ich bin <Bedingung>* ist eine deppenhafte Formulierung. *Ich habe <Bedingung>* ist nur wenig besser.

Comment: @Janka m. A. nach ist "Ich bin auf Bewährung" genausowenig "deppenhaft" wie "ich bin auf Urlaub"

Comment: Letzteres halte ich für ebenso deppenhaft.

Comment: _Unter Bewährung sein_, _Unter Strafe stehen_ wäre mir nicht geläufig. Die "formelle" Formulierung ist _Strafaussetzung zur Bewährung_, allerdings gibt es _Haft auf Bewährung_ (heißt: Die Bewährungszeit ersetzt die Haftstrafe, kann aber bei Verstößen in eine solche umgewandelt werden.) **Edit:** Typos

Comment: Ich würde den zweiten Satz viel lieber als »Ich *habe* drei Jahre auf Bewährung (bekommen)« formulieren. (CC @Janka)

Comment: Ich habe keine Ahnung, was der Titel bedeuten soll.

Comment: @Jan: 3 Jahre auf Bewährung bekommen zu haben sagt etwas anderes aus. Der Satz ist noch richtig, auch wenn die 3 Jahre abgelaufen sind. "Ich bin 3 Jahre auf Bewährung" oder "habe 3 Jahre B." drückt aus, dass die Strafe noch über mir schwebt.

Answer (score 1):

Man kann unter Beobachtung stehen, aber nicht unter Bewährung. Und man kann zwar auf Urlaub sein, aber bei der Frage, ob man »auf Bewährung« sein kann, bin ich persönlich skeptisch. Ich würde diesen Satz nicht so sagen.

Das Problem bei beiden Beispielsätzen ist nämlich, dass die Bewährung in Wahrheit keine Eigenschaft der bestraften Person ist, sondern eine Eigenschaft der ausgesetzten Strafe. Die Haft im Gefängnis wird für eine gewisse Zeitdauer auf Bewährung ausgesetzt, nicht der Sträfling. Folgendes wäre daher korrektes Deutsch:

> Meine Haftstrafe wurde auf Bewährung für drei Jahre ausgesetzt.

oder

> Ich habe eine Bewährungsfrist von drei Jahren bekommen.

(Beachte, dass eine Frist sehr wohl etwas ist, das eine Person haben kann.)

Grammatisch sind beide in der Frage genanten Sätze völlig korrekt, aber der erste ist semantisch unsinnig und der zweite ist zumindest stilistisch kein Glanzlicht.

Aber die Frage lautete nicht, ob diese Sätze korrekt sind. Gefragt wurde:

---

> Hat »unter« die selbe Bedeutung wie »auf«, oder ist die eine Präposition anders als die andere?

Das lässt sich leicht anhand von Beispielen feststellen:

> Das Buch liegt **unter** dem Tisch.
>   Das Buch liegt **auf** dem Tisch.

Das ist wohl nicht ganz genau das gleiche. Folglich haben die beiden Präpositionen unterschiedliche Bedeutung. Ich weiß schon, dass die Frage sich auf »auf Bewährung« und »unter Bewährung« bezogen hat, aber weil »unter Bewährung« keinen Sinn ergibt, fehlt die Basis aufgrund dessen man einen Vergleich überhaupt anstellen könnte.

---

Die zweite Frage war:

> Kann ich in diesem Zusammenhang entweder »stehen« oder »sein« benutzen?

Nachdem »unter Bewährung« keinen Sinn ergibt, bleibt nur »auf Bewährung« um das auszuprobieren:

> Ich stehe drei Jahre auf Bewährung.
>   Ich bin drei Jahre auf Bewährung.

Nein. Das ist nicht dasselbe. Mit »auf etwas stehen« meint man, dass man etwas gerne mag. Das drückt eine große Zuneigung zu dieser Sache aus, die mit heftigem Verlangen nach dieser Sache einhergeht:

> Walter steht auf Currywurst.
>   Ilse steht auf gepunktete Kleider.

Den Ausdruck »auf etwas sein« kenne ich eigentlich nur in diesen beiden Varianten:

> 1. Egon ist auf Drogen.
> 2. Egon ist auf Urlaub.

Falls »auf Bewährung sein« eine einwandfreie Konstruktion ist, hat sie Ähnlichkeit mit 2 (»auf Urlaub sein«). Das bedeutet aber, dass man seine Zeit unter einer besonderen Bedingung verbringt. Es bedeutet nicht, dass man ein heftiges Verlangen nach dieser Sache verspürt.

Daher ist die Frage mit *nein* zu beantworten.

Comment: Eine wohlstrukturierte Antwort, die aber Humbug ist. a) Deine Vorschläge drücken nicht aus, dass die Strafandrohung noch andauert. b) Man kann auch unter Aufsicht stehen oder unter Verdacht c) Man kann auch auf Kriegsfuß mit jmd. stehen - das heißt nicht, dass man in den Kriegsfuß verliebt ist.